# How do I use PowerShell to pull headers from a OneNote document

Tags: powershell, ms-office, hierarchy, onenote

**Background:** 
In my work environment, we have a transitional location for our knowledgebase notes.  These reside in a number of OneNote 2016 workbooks which have been maintained over years.  I am currently in the middle of delegating content update efforts to our staff and part of this work involves importing all our OneNote notebook names and section names into an excel spreadsheet for hierarchy management.

**Task:**  I spent ages looking online for an easy and quick way to export hierarchy information from OneNote to csv using PowerShell and could not for the life of me find an easy way that worked.  The following code resonated through the interwebs but each time I tried to run the code, I kept getting errors.

```
$onenote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
$scope = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages
[ref]$xml = $null

$onenote.GetHierarchy($null, $scope, $xml)

$schema = @{one=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote”}

$xpath = “//one:Notebook/one:Section”
Select-Xml -Xml (

$xml.Value) -Namespace $schema -XPath $xpath |
foreach {
$node = $psitem.Node

$npath = Split-Path -Path $node.Path -Parent

$props = [ordered]@{
Workbook =  Split-Path -Path $npath -Leaf
Section = $node.Name
}
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
}
```

**Error:**
The error I would get from executing this code was as follows:

*value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode".
At line:10 char:17
+ Select-Xml -Xml (*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**
In the end I had to break down the established connection to the Onenote Application and found a workable solution for OneNote 2016.  I've provided my solution but am keen to hear of any other possible ways to manipulate this data effectively in the future:

```
Function Get-OneNoteHeaders{ 

[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

Begin
{
    $onenote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
    $scope = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages
    [ref]$xml = $null
    $csvOutput = "c:\temp\onenote-headers.csv"
}
Process
{     
    $onenote.GetHierarchy($null, $scope, $xml)
    [xml]$result = ($xml.Value)

    Foreach($notebook in $($result.DocumentElement.Notebook)){
        Add-content -Path $csvOutput -Value "$($notebook.name)"
        Foreach($section in $($notebook.section)){
            Add-content -Path $csvOutput -Value ",$($section.name)"
            Foreach($page in $section.page){
                Add-content -Path $csvOutput -Value ",,$($page.name)"
            }
        }
    }
}
End{}
}

#Get-OneNoteHeaders
```

Comment: First of all, nice job. Second: are you using only the desktop version of onenote w/o synchronisation via O356/onedrive? If you do sync online it might be worth looking at the Microsoft Graph Api. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @Adamar !  Yeah sadly, we're not quite in the cloud just yet over here but I'll keep that feature in mind when our systems 'vapourize' (cheesy joke there sorry)

Comment: Just one little thing: There is no need in Powershell to cleanup variables, like you did in the `End{}`. It might look nicer, but it's worth nothing. By the way: Shouldn't removing the variables with `Remove-Variable` make more sense, than just nulling them?

Comment: Ahh interesting point.   And yes I think you're right about remove-var.. better practise I guess.  But by that logic shouldn't new-var and set-var also be used?